# Bootstrap 3.3.7 affix bottom navbar flickering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, affix

I'm trying to get a navbar that is placed at the very bottom of the page to be sticky at the bottom of the screen when it is scrolled out of view.

I have put the following attributes on the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-bottom="350">
```

And css:

```
.affix { bottom: 0; }
```

When scrolling down the page the navbar is sticky as it should be. When you reach the offset-bottom the class 'affix' should change to 'affix-bottom'. At this point the navbar starts flickering. When inspecting the DOM you can see that it switches the class affix/affix-bottom every pixel.

When using data-offset-top to achieve a top sticky navbar all works fine.

I can reproduce my issue on the w3schools example of the bootstrap affix plugin (don't forget to click 'run'):
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FPAH8DBTOHUV

As you can see the navbar will start flickering when you scroll to the very end of the page. Any ideaus what is causing this strange behaviour?

Edit: There are a lot of threads about this issue but none of them really have a solution, or at least a solution that works in my w3schools example:

- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6575
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4647
- [Bootstrap Affix Classes Jumping at Bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022448/bootstrap-affix-classes-jumping-at-bottom)